# Upload an Base64 Encoded Image through retrofit2 returning null responce

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I'm trying to upload a Base64 image string using retrofit. but it's not working.

This is my interface

```
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("index.php?r=unifyservice/savepropdocs_base64")
    Call<uploadResponce> UploadImage(@Field("fileName") String FileName,
                                     @Field("proposal_No") String ProposalNo,
                                     @Field("agent_code") String AgentCode,
                                     @Field("category") String Category,
                                     @Field("myupload") String Base64Image
    );
```

and this is my call.
I have a pojo `Object` with the Base64 String `"Data.getMyupload()"`

```
        ApiInterface apiInterface = ApiClient.getClient_myarena().create(ApiInterface.class);
        Call<uploadResponce> call = apiInterface.UploadImage(
                Data.getFileName(),
                Data.getProposal_No(),
                Data.getAgent_code(),
                Data.getCategory(),
                Data.getMyupload()
        );
        //Call<uploadResponce> call = apiInterface.UploadImage("application/json", Data);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<uploadResponce>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<uploadResponce> call, Response<uploadResponce> response) {

                System.out.println("sdfdsf " + response.body().toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<uploadResponce> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("AAA Image Upload ", t.toString());

            }
        });
```

and this is what I get when I run the application
it crash and gives this Exception

```
2019-07-05 19:52:50.133 8563-8563/lk.allianz.damitht.eproposal E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: lk.allianz.damitht.eproposal, PID: 8563
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String lk.allianz.damitht.eproposal.model.ArenaUpload.uploadResponce.toString()' on a null object reference
        at lk.allianz.damitht.eproposal.fragments.ArenaUploads$12.onResponse(ArenaUploads.java:1005)
        at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:68)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

> **Find a solution for this**,

1. Create a `Bitmap` file from Image Path and convert it into `byte[]`

```
    private byte[] convertToBase64(String imagePath) {

        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath);

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos); //bm is the bitmap object
        byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();

        return b;
    }
```

2. use `Base64.encodeToString` to get the Base64 String.

```
    Base64.encodeToString(convertToBase64 (imagePath), Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Comment: Does the API accept FormUrlEncoded or Json?

Comment: @IsraeldelaCruz - it accept FormUrlEncoded

Answer (score 0):

It seems your response body is `null`. You should check if your api-call is a success before consuming the response:

```
call.enqueue(new Callback<uploadResponce>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<UploadResponce> call, Response<uploadResponce> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
             UploadResponceitem uploadResponce = response.body();
              if (uploadResponce != null) {
               System.out.println("sdfdsf " + uploadResponce.toString());
              }
             } 
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<uploadResponce> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("AAA Image Upload ", t.toString());

            }
        });
```